# sem_wait() in producer and consumer

Tags: c

This is my code for producer and consumer problem. It can be compiled, but when I run the program it print nothing. I test the program and found the problem maybe about sem_wait(). Why the program could be compiled but the output is wrong? Thank you.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    empty = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, BUFFER_SIZE);
    full = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

    pthread_create(&pro_thread, NULL, producer, NULL);
    pthread_create(&con_thread, NULL, consumer, NULL);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Is the sem_open() function right? I commented the following line and the program could run...maybe the problem is about sem_open?

```
empty = sem_open("/mysem", O_CREAT, 0644, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your producer never produces anything

Check the semaphore names. May be `empty` and `full` are the same instance as you're using the same name for both in your `sem_open` function

Comment: I'm not agree with you. Initially, counter is 0 and BUFFER_SIZE is 10, so the producer will not go to the while loop.

Comment: For producer, if the buffer is full which means counter == BUFFER_SIZE, the producer will stop producing, so the producer will stop. Initially, there no item in the buffer, so the producer could produce something.

Comment: You're right, I saw it wrong... In thinking if the pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); makes the consumer takes the lock and wait forever in its while loop. In that case producer will never produce anything because is waiting for the consumer to free the mutex

Comment: I find another problem.. If I delete the sem_open for empty and full, the program will run correctly. But I don't know why, could you please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Check this link http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html as your giving the same name, it seems that both empty and full are the same instance

Comment: Thank you Jorge. I have figured out the problem. I just use the same name of empty and full in sem_open(). It should be different.